# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have created list and trying to assign it to StructType() but getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import logging
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, dayofmonth
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import argparse

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename = 'parquet.log')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--schema_py', '--list', nargs='+', required=True, dest='schema_py', help='Scheam def')

args = parser.parse_args()

schemaField = args.schema_py
print(type(schemaField))   #It will print <class 'list'>

schema = StructType(schemaField) # On this line facing issue
print(type(schema))
```

Output

```
$ python tst.py --schema_py 'StructField('col1', StringType(), True),StructField('col2', StringType(), True),StructField('col3', StringType(), True),StructField('col4', StringType(), True),'

<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brrConvertParquet.py", line 41, in <module>
    schema = StructType(schemaField)
  File "/home/sysbrrd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 484, in __init__
    self.names = [f.name for f in fields]
  File "/home/sysbrrd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 484, in <listcomp>
    self.names = [f.name for f in fields]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Please help me to understand what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems i see are:

1. You are passing a `str` into the `StructType()` call, rather than a list of `[StructField(),]` or since you have `nargs='+'` maybe you are passing in a list of strings. i.e.
   `["StructField('col1', StringType(), True)", "StructField('col2',
   StringType(), True)", "StructField('col3', StringType(),
   True)", "StructField('col4', StringType(), True)"]`.
2. If you really want to receive the fields as a cmd arg, then you should look into validating this arg and converting it into the desired python type. You can look into `json`, `pickle`, `eval` or `exec`.

Asides that, everything else should work.

`self.names = [f.name for f in fields]` breaks because `fields` is a `str` rather than a list of `StructField`, if it were a list of `StructField` as expected, the `f.name` call should work just fine :-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: :- Thanks for the answer! I am able to sort this, the problem is the same what you have explained here. As the dataType I was passing is in string format so I have typeCasted it to required pyspark dataType and it worked.

Comment: @SwapnilM If the answer is correct and it describes the solution to the problem you were having, maybe you should mark it as answered. That's the way `Stack overflow` works at least.

Comment: @SwapnilM I see that you were able to resolve the problem. I am facing the same issue. I have a schema file in cloud storage in txt format. ```[StructField('col1', StructType([ 
    StructField('_data', StringType(), True) ])), 
StructField('clusterTime', StructType([        
    StructField('_timestamp' , StructType([ StructField('i',IntegerType(), True)]))]))]```

I am getting same issue  as you have mentioned at this line ```final_struct = StructType(fields=data_schema)```.
Could you pls let me know how did you resolve this